# Need a help with a jquery click count

Tags: jquery

So far I have got this JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#flash").click(function() {
        $(this).html('<img src="http://ruh.kz/sites/default/files/ajax-loader.gif" />');
        $(this).load("http://ruh.kz/sites/all/themes/ruh/sunit.php");
        $('#counter').html(function(i, val) {
            return val * 1 + 1
        });
    });
});
```

Accompanying this HTML:

```
<div id="flash">
    <img src="http://ruh.kz/sites/default/files/sunit.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="counter">0</div>
```

[(Demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/MuG2U/1/)

1. One problem is that it resets after the page refreshes... How can I save the count number?
2. In [the example on jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/MuG2U/1/), it works well. On my Drupal page however, it doesn't. When I press on the `<div id="flash">` the counter "0" dissapears. What might be the problem here?

Comment: Heihachi: In future, can you include your code **in** the question as well as linking to it on jsfiddle? StackOverflow questions should stand alone from anything else!

Answer (score 0):

1. You will have to use cookies to store the number of clicks between page requests, as on each reload the javascript will be reloaded and so your click counts will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can post ajax request to save it or save it to [cookies](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.cookie.js.txt)
2. DO you have #counter there?

Comment: Can you throw me an example. 2- Yes, i hve <div id="counter">

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned here, cookies are one solution to storing the number of clicks across page refreshes. Another option is to store them in a database, associated with the logged in user. Cookies would certainly be much simpler, but if you're running this on a Drupal site and have decent PHP/MySQL experience then the database option is easy enough as well. Mainly, it depends on how critical this click count is. Does it need to be saved permanently? Should a user see the correct number no matter what computer he/she is using? If the answer to either of these questions is "yes", then the database solution is required.

As for why it's not working on your Drupal site, you'll have to provide more info. Do you get any JavaScript errors in your console?